# Joint distribution from pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has two columns `A` and `B`, both of which contain numbers. I want to create a joint distribution from these columns, ie. I want to bin both columns (where each bin of `A` contains every bin of `B`, and so on for a joint distribution) and assign numbers in each row to one of the bins. At the end I should get a distribution of the counts of rows in each bin.

Is there a function to do this, or do I have to write a method myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can cut `A` and `B` into their own bins, then apply a `groupby` to count them:

```
# Some sample input data
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 1000, (1000, 2)), columns=['A', 'B'])

# Assign values in columns A & B into 5 bins each
# The bins in A are independent of the bins in B
df['BinA'] = pd.cut(df['A'], 5, labels=[f'a{i}' for i in range(1,6)])
df['BinB'] = pd.cut(df['B'], 5, labels=[f'b{i}' for i in range(1,6)])

# The count
df.groupby(['BinA', 'BinB']).count()
```

Result:

```
            A   B
BinA BinB        
a1   b1    44  44
     b2    39  39
     b3    35  35
     b4    53  53
     b5    41  41
a2   b1    40  40
     b2    36  36
     b3    34  34
     b4    33  33
     b5    31  31
a3   b1    35  35
     b2    44  44
     b3    30  30
     b4    31  31
     b5    39  39
a4   b1    48  48
     b2    38  38
     b3    46  46
     b4    37  37
     b5    43  43
a5   b1    50  50
     b2    43  43
     b3    36  36
     b4    50  50
     b5    44  44
```